# Bind dataTemplate to external Data Source

Tags: wpf, xaml, nhibernate, data-binding

i have this DataTemplate:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:Model="clr-namespace:Effectus.Model"
xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=WPFToolkit"
>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Model:ToDoAction}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="Title" 
                   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Title}"
                   IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}},Path=DataContext.AllowEditing.Value}"
                   Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Content" 
                   Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Content}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}},Path=DataContext.AllowEditing.Value}"
            AcceptsReturn="True"
            MinHeight="100"
            Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Owner"
                   Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Owner}" DisplayMemberPath="Username" SelectedValuePath="Username"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource EnumValuesConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Type Model:Status}}"
                  IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}},Path=DataContext.AllowEditing.Value}"
                  Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1"/>

    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

In the last part you can see a TextBlock whose Text is "Owner", followed by a ComboBox.
Just to give you the context, this is a little part of a ToDo app that i'm currently working on (i'm trying to get into MVVM).
The XAML i poted is the DataTemplate of the ToDoAction objects.
I want the "Owner" ComboBox to be filled by all users. I can get them from DB through NHibernate but i don't have the faintest idea on how to bind the DataTemplate to my DataSource (a Nhibernate Session in my case, but i feel this is more general).
Can you give some little advise please?
Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to handle that like the [ObjectDataProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider.aspx) which i never used. But i think the most easiest and fastest is to use a singleton.

```
public sealed class UserList
{
    public ObservableCollection<User> Users {get; private set;}

    public static UserList Instance
    {
        get{return sInstance;}
    }

    private static UserList sInstance = new UserList();
}
```

you can update and modify the Users list as usual and the bindings to this collection must be.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static my:UserList.Instance}, Path=Users}
```

Comment: That would work of course, but won't it break good design priciples behind MVVM? I mean, i already have a well defined data source (NHibernate's ISession). Adding a static one like you suggested would cause doubling data source. Moreover, when i add a new User, the list would not be updated automatically... i'll have to call UserList.Instance().Add(newUser); Any other idea?

Comment: In theory you are correct it always can be nicer. But personaly i always know that a datasource which i didn't create my self (like a direct table pointer, or an xml file or using objectdataprovider) will sooner or later not be enough and i have to work around it. Thats why i prefere the simpler solutions because its easier to build on top of them instead of work around a preexisting solution. But i have no knowledge about NHibernate so maybe this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36109/The-WPF-NHibernate-Toolkit) is of more use.

Comment: I accepted your answer as it gives the right direction. Well, not perfect as you agreed, but not bad too. It is a good payoff in my opinion. Thanks!